# Current year in Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need 2019 to be the current year, what's the variable in these Firebase rules for the current year, if there's one?

My Firebase rules:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "statistics": {
      "2019": {
        "total": {
        ".read": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable for current year.  There is a variable called [`now`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#now) for current time in milliseconds since unix epoch.  You could derive the year from that time.  If you use a web tool such as [this](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) to find the start and end of 2019 in unix time, you'll discover that the start is 1546300800 and the end is 1577836800.  But that's if your timezone is UTC, which may not be what you want.  So you'll have to be specific about exactly when you believe 2019 starts and ends for the users of your app.